# Unknown lifecycle phase maven

Tags: maven-3

I am new to maven and camel.

I tried executing the examples in camel book. And I am getting this error when I run the following command.

**Command:**

```
mvn test -Dtest= SpringTransformMethodTest
```

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "SpringTransformMethodTest". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the f
ormat <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle ph
ases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, proce
ss-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile,
process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, ver
ify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles.`
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you have likely a **space** between `-Dtest=` and `SpringTransformMethodTest`. That's then interpreted as 2 items instead of one.

Comment: @user2761267 if it works for you then you can tick this answer as ACCEPTED.

Comment: @mkleint Perfect. Thanks !! However, I don't understand how the error message/description is related to the actual error.

Comment: @node_saini well, the -Dtest= is interpreted as single parameter and SpringTransformMethodTest as another. because SpringTransformMethodTest doesn't have - prepended and doesn't contain : (that would be a plugin goal) it's interpreted as a lifecycle stage but is not found in the list.

Answer (score 34):

If the parameter name is not a single 'word' you might also need to enclose it in quotation marks like this:

```
mvn gatling:test -D"gatling.simulationClass"="my.package.PostmanSimulation"
```

Comment: Tarmo's answer may not apply if you are using linux or git bash in windows, but is definitely needed on powershell (default terminal for Windows on IntelliJ in my case). You can also just create a space after -D to avoid using quotes which I feel is a bit cleaner and legible

Answer (score 18):

This error has happened to me as well. I was running this command which hasn't spaces between the parameters of mvn install its values.

With this command:

```
> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file 
-Dfile=C:\Users\arcones\Desktop\ojdbc7.jar 
-DgroupId=com.oracle 
-DartifactId=ojdbc7 
-Dversion=12.1.0.1 
-Dpackaging=jar 
-DlocalRepositoryPath=lib
```

I got this error:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".oracle". You must specify a valid
>   lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or
>   :[:]:.
>   Available lifecycle phases are: validate , initialize,
>   generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
>   process-resources, compile, process-classes, genera te-test-sources,
>   process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
>   test-compile, process-test-class es, test, prepare-package, package,
>   pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
>   install, depl oy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site,
>   post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]

The problem got resolved by adding double quotes to each value:

```
> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file 
-Dfile="C:\Users\arcones\Desktop\ojdbc7.jar" 
-DgroupId="com.oracle"
-DartifactId="ojdbc7"
-Dversion="12.1.0.1"
-Dpackaging="jar" 
-DlocalRepositoryPath="lib"
```

> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: If you're using Windows, don't use powershell - I had more luck in the default cmd prompt

Comment: Works with powershell but needs double qoutes

Comment: In Powershell it worked for me as example ` mvn spring-boot:run "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev"` => see double quotes

Comment: thanks. thanks. (stack arbitrarily forced me to write a longer message)

Answer (score 1):

Accidentially typing:

> **mvn packgage**

Instead of:

> **mvn package**

Yeilds/Results In:

> **[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "packgage".** [ ...etc...]

*Stack: GitBash+Windows10+Maven3.5.4*

Answer (score 1):

I got the error also

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "pacakge". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

you may type wrong command
change 'pacakge' to 'package'

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if creating a shell script file when working with Dockerfile.
It's recommended to not have any blank spaces. This is a valid working sample:

```
         RUN echo $'#!/bin/bash\n\
         \n\n\
         mvn -e -B clean install\\\n\
         -Dparam1=\"${PARAM1}\"\\\n\
         -Dparam1=\"${PARAM2}\"\\\n\
         -Dsurefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests=false\\\n\
         -DfailIfNoTests=false\\\n\
         -Dtest=\"!SomeTest,AnotherTest\"\n\
         \n\n' > start.sh

         RUN cat ./start.sh
 
         RUN chmod +x ./start.sh
 
         RUN ./start.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run it on IntelliJ MVN terminal using these commands on windows machine.

mvn clean install -PrunBDDTests "-Dcucumber.filter.tags=@SauceDemoTest" -DTestConfiguration=LOCALChrome

mvn clean install -PrunBDDTests "-Dcucumber.filter.tags=@SauceDemoTest" "-DTestConfiguration=SaucelabsWebChrome"

Answer (score -1):

The problem is also untrimmed strings, not only with blanks into it.

To reproduce, use an untrimmed string variable to pass arguments

```
toto=" -DskipTests "
mvn install ${toto}  
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "  -DskipTests "
```

To fix it, use a simple `xargs` to trim the arguments variable.

```
toto=" -DskipTests "
toto=$(echo "$toto"|xargs)            
mvn install ${toto}
```

Works with multiple arguments too:

```
toto="  -DskipTests -DotherVal=1  "
```

*Stack*: Ubuntu20.4 + Mvn3.8.3  + zsh5.8 + oh-my-zsh